# how to transform a set of pixels into an image with opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, pixel

i'm new to opencv and i want to build an image with pixels that I have saved in a file, the first thing I do is pass them to a vector, but then I want to transform it into my image where I have not achieved it, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right or if I can do in a better way

```
pixels = fopen("arch.txt", "r");

for(int i=0;i<19200;i++){
    fscanf(pixels, "%x", img[i]);
}

fclose(pixels);
Mat imagen(160,120,img[0]);
outImg = imagen.reshape(1,160*120);
imwrite("capture.jpg", outImg);
```

I've searched a lot on this topic, but I did not find anything to help me do it.

Comment: How are the image data stored in arch.txt?

Comment: `fscanf(pixels, "%x", img[i]);` should be `fscanf(pixels, "%x", &img[i]);` to take the address of the i'th element. `Mat imagen(160,120,img[0]);` is going to do something weird - the first pixel value is interpreted as the depth of the array, and again you need to take the address of the first element to use as the data pointer. Try `Mat imagen(160,120,CV_8U,&img[0]);`. Mat constructor takes the rows first, then cols, so if your image is 160x120 you actually want `Mat imagen(120,160...`

Comment: Don't use `fopen`, `fclose`, `fscanf` in C++ code. Other issues: follow advice of @Chungzuwalla

Comment: thank you very much for the corrections, I got the image.